# How to hide .jar source code in Android Studio?

Tags: android, jar, hide

I am trying to create a jar library in Android Studio. I would like to hide my code **totally** which inside .jar library because other people shouldn't see my source code.
I am using proguard to shuffle and it is hiding some stuff from code. But It doesn't block to click and go source code flow. Can I totally block click and go flow to hide my source code?

Comment: A JAR contains compiled code, not source code.

Comment: Yes, it could be. But some of code parts appear when click library methods.